# encrypt soap message using x509 certificate

Tags: c++, soap, openssl, x509certificate, x509

I'm trying to understand how x509 certificate works with openssl and encrypt soap message. I am using lib-wsdlpull library to creare soap message. So I added method to reproduce this example header: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.3.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc/wsSecurity/dfhws_soapmsg_signed.html

According to this example I need:

1. The binary security token contains the base64binary encoding of the X.509 certificate. This encoding includes the public key that the intended recipient of the SOAP message uses to verify the signature.

I have following code that I believe give me X.509 certificate

```
#include "openssl/bio.h"
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"
#include "openssl/x509.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char *base64(const unsigned char *input, unsigned int length)
{
        BIO *bmem, *b64;
        BUF_MEM *bptr;

        b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
        bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
        b64 = BIO_push(b64, bmem);
        BIO_write(b64, input, length);
        BIO_flush(b64);
        BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64, &bptr);

        char *buff = (char *)malloc(bptr->length);
        memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length - 1);
        buff[bptr->length - 1] = 0;

        BIO_free_all(b64);

        return buff;
}

/*
 * generates a key pair
 * */
EVP_PKEY* generateKeyPair(){
        int bits = 2048;        /* number of bits for the key - 2048 is a sensible value */

        EVP_PKEY * pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
        RSA* rsa = RSA_new();

        BIGNUM *bne = BN_new();
        BN_set_word(bne, RSA_F4);       /* exponent - RSA_F4 is defined as 0x10001L */
        if ( RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, bits, bne, NULL) == 0 ){
                BN_free(bne);
                RSA_free(rsa);

                return NULL;
        }

        BN_free(bne);

        EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsa);

        return pkey;
}

X509* createCertificate(){
    X509* x509 = X509_new();

    if ( x509 == NULL ){
            return NULL;
    }

    ASN1_INTEGER_set(X509_get_serialNumber(x509), 1);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notBefore(x509), 0);
    X509_gmtime_adj(X509_get_notAfter(x509), 31536000L);

    return x509;
}

void setPublicKey(X509* x509, EVP_PKEY* pkey){
        X509_set_pubkey(x509, pkey);
}

void signCertificate(X509* x509, EVP_PKEY* pkey){
        X509_sign(x509, pkey, EVP_sha1());
}

void writePrivateKey( EVP_PKEY* pkey, const char* fileName ){

    FILE * f;
    f = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    PEM_write_PrivateKey(
                    f,                  /* write the key to the file we've opened */
                    pkey,               /* our key from earlier */
                    NULL, /* default cipher for encrypting the key on disk */
                    NULL,       /* passphrase required for decrypting the key on disk */
                    10,                 /* length of the passphrase string */
                    NULL,               /* callback for requesting a password */
                    NULL                /* data to pass to the callback */
                    );
}

void writeCertificate( X509* x509, const char* fileName ){

    FILE * f;
    f = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    PEM_write_X509(
                    f,   /* write the certificate to the file we've opened */
                    x509 /* our certificate */
                  );
}

const EVP_MD* digestMessage( const char* digestName, const std::string& strToEncode, unsigned char **digestValue, unsigned int& digestLen ){
        const EVP_MD *digest = EVP_get_digestbyname(digestName);
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, digest, NULL);

    EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, strToEncode.c_str(), strToEncode.size());

    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, *digestValue, &digestLen);
    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);

    return digest;
}

int main(){

    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

    EVP_PKEY * pkey = generateKeyPair();
    if ( pkey == NULL ){
            puts("Something went wrong when generating private key");

            return -1;
    }

    X509* x509 = createCertificate();
    if ( x509 == NULL ){
            puts("Something went wrong when generating certificate");

            return -1;
    }

    setPublicKey( x509, pkey );
    signCertificate( x509, pkey );

    writePrivateKey( pkey, "privatekey.pem" );
    writeCertificate( x509, "cert.pem" );
```

As I understand in cert.pem I have that X.509 certificate

So next step is
3.The value of the message digest.

And I have following code for this

```
unsigned char* digestValue = new unsigned char[10000];
        unsigned int digestLen = 0;
        std::string textToSign = "test32131654564627863276837243286324eroi5t5twutaergeahnuihnuigyniguyfgnufutfgbuuuyggygykgygjhggyjjkjkggjhkjggjjkgjkggyjkhgyjkggyg6567578576tyuiytrfv76igrtuigrtuigbrtgrbtuuutuftffgfffff ytffhfhgfhfhgfhgfhfhgfyty54u5654u5rgu5rfguytrfrttttttyyyttgh   gf";
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;
        textToSign += textToSign;

const EVP_MD* digest = digestMessage( "sha1", textToSign, &digestValue, digestLen );
```

And all what I don't understand and missing is last step
4.The digest value is then encrypted with the user's private key and included here as the signature value

I do not know what o handle this... can anybody help with that?

I wrote this

```
X509_digest(x509, digest, digestValue, &digestLen);
```

but I'm not sure whether it makes sense...